# Should I be concerned about Yarn warnings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webpack, webpack-dev-server, yarnpkg

```
OS: Mac Mojave 10.14.3
```

My Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
git_source(:github) { |repo| "https://github.com/#{repo}.git" }
ruby '2.6.0'
gem 'rails', '~> 5.2.2'
gem 'mysql2', '>= 0.4.4', '< 0.6.0'
gem 'puma', '~> 3.11'
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
gem 'webpacker'
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.2'
gem 'turbolinks', '~> 5'
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.5'
gem 'bootsnap', '>= 1.1.0', require: false
group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
end
group :development do
  gem 'web-console', '>= 3.3.0'
  gem 'listen', '>= 3.0.5', '< 3.2'
  gem 'spring'
  gem 'spring-watcher-listen', '~> 2.0.0'
end
group :test do
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

bundle install does not produce any errors.

If I do:

```
yarn add moment
```

Here's what I see:

```
yarn add v1.13.0
1/4]   Resolving packages...
[2/4]   Fetching packages...
[3/4]   Linking dependencies...
warning "@rails/webpacker > postcss-cssnext@3.1.0" has unmet peer dependency "caniuse-lite@^1.0.30000697".
warning " > webpack-dev-server@2.11.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^2.2.0 || ^3.0.0".
warning "webpack-dev-server > webpack-dev-middleware@1.12.2" has unmet peer dependency "webpack@^1.0.0 || ^2.0.0 || ^3.0.0".
[4/4]   Building fresh packages...
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ moment@2.24.0
info All dependencies
└─ moment@2.24.0
✨  Done in 2.01s.
```

I tried googling these errors, but I did not get far. I did get the "success saved one new dependency, but I can't imagine this will run successfully with all these warnings. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Peer dependencies are ones that the project assumes you have installed. You can install them to have the warnings go away. You need to install them manually, just do a `yarn add` on the needed dependencies.

It's right in that message, it says which deps you're missing (caniuse-lite, webpack)

Comment: This solved the problem. I am new to using yarn, and I was under the impression that I was running into a bug, as I thought yarn would take care of it